# Implementation of function in class derived from template class

Tags: c++, class, templates, implementation, derived

There's an error when I try to compile the implem.cpp file: It looks like the compiler doesn't know what `klasa*` is. It calls for template arguments. It works when I put the definition of `fun` into the class body.

header.h

```
// ... couple of includes
using namespace std;

template <class typ>
class klasa {
    typ i;
    virtual klasa* fun()=0;
};
```

header2.h

```
#include "header.h"

class klasa2 : public klasa<int>{
    klasa* fun();
};
```

h2_implem.cpp

```
#include "header2.h"

klasa* klasa2::fun(){
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: That's the correct behaviour. You can use `klasa` with template arguments omitted inside `klasa` and its derived classes, but not outsude.

Comment: wow, even if its only implementation of function of derived class?

Comment: Note that this *does* work in C++11's *trailing-return-types* : `auto klasa2::fun() -> klasa* { return nullptr; }`